# Image Editor 2D gizmo name?

Tags: python, scripting, uv-image-editor, gizmo

Hi I am trying to create a tool that has a gizmo in the 2d/Image-editor view.
When adding a gizmo I use the `self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_dial_3d")` to display a radial gizmo.
However I saw in the [release notes for 2.82](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/UI) there is a 2d gizmo that you now can display in UV view.
I would like to know what its name is so I can use it for my tool, `self.gizmos.new("UV_WIDGET_NAME?")`

If you know anything about this or somewhere I can see all listed types of gizmos that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** The UV translate tool uses `GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d`.

---

The gizmo groups that are used for the tools in the UV editor can be seen in `_defs_image_uv_transform` ([space_toolsystem_toolbar.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_toolsystem_toolbar.py)).

The ID name of the gizmo group is `IMAGE_GGT_gizmo2d_translate` which is implemented in [space_image.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_image/space_image.c). It uses `ED_widgetgroup_gizmo2d_xform_no_cage_callbacks_set`, which in turn calls `ED_widgetgroup_gizmo2d_xform_callbacks_set`  that stores `gizmo2d_xform_setup` as function for the setup. Should the setup function be called this also results in `gizmogroup2d_init` being executed. Its return value is a `GizmoGroup2D` that is used to set gizmos for the operators through `WM_gizmo_operator_set`. The gizmo types that are returned by `gizmogroup2d_init` in a `GizmoGroup2D` are `GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d`, `GIZMO_GT_cage_2d` and `GIZMO_GT_button_2d`.

These functions are implemented in [transform_gizmo_2d.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/transform/transform_gizmo_2d.c).

Comment: Thanks man this info is pure gold! :)

Comment: A follow up question, is it possible to use IMAGE_GGT_gizmo2d_translate for a operator of my own, or is the best way to just try to recreate something similar in a GizmoGroup by myself?
I have tried to use GIZMO_GT_arrow_3d in IMAGE_EDITOR context but I instantly get a crash when I try to drag it.
I also have the problem with the coordinate system for the gizmo being in region space, since I want to align it to stuff like verts or 2D cursor in UV/View space.

Comment: @legendari I haven't tried to do that. It should be possible to recreate the settings from `gizmogroup2d_init` in your own gizmo group. It could be that you can just reuse `IMAGE_GGT_gizmo2d_translate`, but I haven't tested it and there may be issues that I haven't seen. Unfortunately I'm a bit busy at the moment, which is why I likely won't be able to investigate this further. Perhaps someone else will post an example or I will revisit this in the future.